# Wampserver loglevel rewrite not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wampserver

I am using [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com) and I would like to debug my rewrite rules from .htaccess, since I still receive 404 errors.

I already enabled rewrite_module, log_debug_module, log_forensic_module and log_config_module, but in my error log I don't receive any information about .htaccess.

In httpd.conf I changed `LogLevel`to: `LogLevel warn mod_rewrite.c:trace8`. I also tried the following options: `rewrite_module`, `mod_rewrite.so`, `rewrite`, `mod_rewrite`.

Then when I restart the server I only get this log, but I don't receive anything about web requests when I try to go to `localhost/mysite`.

```
[Sat Oct 12 17:33:07.063441 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8884:tid 412] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Sat Oct 12 17:33:09.063556 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1632:tid 288] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Sat Oct 12 17:33:09.078557 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8884:tid 412] AH00430: Parent: Child process 1632 exited successfully.
[Sat Oct 12 17:33:48.859832 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8252:tid 412] AH00455: Apache/2.4.4 (Win64) PHP/5.4.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Oct 12 17:33:48.859832 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8252:tid 412] AH00456: Server built: Feb 22 2013 22:08:37
[Sat Oct 12 17:33:48.859832 2013] [core:notice] [pid 8252:tid 412] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.4\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4'
[Sat Oct 12 17:33:48.867833 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8252:tid 412] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 6216
[Sat Oct 12 17:33:49.145848 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6216:tid 288] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

**UPDATE**
Here is some more information about my folder structure. I have put my DirectoryRoot to `D:/www` and my `.htaccess` file is in `D:/www/mysite`.

Some parts from httpd.conf:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "D:/www"
<Directory "D:/wamp/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All

#    Require all granted
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from all
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
     Allow from localhost
</Directory>

#ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
ErrorLog "c:/wamp/logs/apache_error.log"

#
# LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
#
LogLevel warn rewrite:trace3
```

Disabling the rewritemodule gives errors on `RewriteEngine` so I suppose that it does find my .htaccess file.

This is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ index.php/$1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be that you are using `Apache 2.4.x`, if so they have made major changes in the area of logging.

Try

```
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3
```

Also another change is that logged info gets written to the normal error_log file.

[Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

***ADDED After Additional Info added***

You have some fairly obvious errors in your httpd.conf file.

Can I suggest you review this document on the WAMPServer forum  [Wampserver 2.4 What to do after Installing](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,118138)

I just changed my WAMPServer Apache conf as so:

```
LogLevel warn rewrite:trace8
```

And got lots of extra lines in my apache_error.log from the rewrite module.

Make sure you are actually running something on the server that will exercise mod_rewrite and the RewriteRule you have in your `.htaccess`

ERRORS:

```
#WRONG Allows access to the root of your D: drive and all subfolders, great for hackers
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#CORRECTED
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

.

```
#WRONG
DocumentRoot "D:/www"

#CORRECTED
DocumentRoot "d:/wamp/www"
```

.

```
#WRONG
<Directory "D:/wamp/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All

#    Require all granted
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from all
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
     Allow from localhost
</Directory>


#CORRECTED
<Directory "D:/wamp/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All

#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
     Require local
</Directory>
```

Comment: Yes I've tried this combination as well and I'm using 2.4.4. Still I don't receive any debug information. I will update my question with some more information about the folder structure and httpd.conf parts.

Comment: See additional info in my answer.

Comment: I've tried to make the changes you told me, but it doesn't seem to work. `Require all denied` doesn't give me any rights and returns 403. And I've also tried the changes in the document, but those don't seem to help either.

Comment: Found my error while staring at it for a long time. It says `<Directory "D:/wamp/www">` and not `<Directory "D:/www"`>

Comment: Well actually it should say `D:/wamp/www` in both cases

Answer (score 1):

After editting yor 'httpd.conf' log to

```
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3
```

You should restart apache server to apply changes.